# How can uwsgi re-establish connection to remote mysql database whenever mysql services are restarted

Tags: python, mysql, web-services, flask, uwsgi

I have a python web application, where in, the application connects to a remote database.

Application: flask+uwsgi+nginx .

Database :mysql (remote).
The application exposes rest api for which data is served from remote database.

Everyday after db restoration, mysql service is restarted in the remote database. The connection between my application and remote database breaks, and it starts throwing error message

```
MySQL server has gone away.
```

until I manually restart the uwsgi service in my application

```
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

The duration between mysql service restart in remote db and uwsgi service restart in my system is the **downtime**.

Can my application re establish connection as soon as the mysql services are restarted ?

Please suggest any solutions?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database. Most connection pools should be able to handle reopening closed connections.

Comment: I it really necessary to restart the database every day? If it really is, if it's done by a script, have the script restart your uwsgi via ssh?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the way you connect to your database

In case you're using the popular ORMs:

- SQLAlchemy ORM

  engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://...', pool_recycle=3600)

  as stated in the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=pool_recycle#connection-timeouts)
- Peewee

  ```py
  @app.before_request
     def _db_connect():
         database.connect()


  @app.teardown_request
  def _db_close(exc):
      if not database.is_closed():
          database.close()
  ```

  as stated in the documentation [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#adding-request-hooks)

The issue is explained in depth in the mysql documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: I am not using ORM.